# how to create plan subscription in wordpress plugin so no one can play with the code?

Tags: wordpress

I am confuse about plan subscription development in plugin, because if user download the whole plugin coding file then he/she can change the any of the code in plugin.

so how can develop this type of plugin. And also backupbuddy, gravityforms also make this type of annual subscription plan and if user make to code change in backupbuddy then deactivate the plugin but i can't understand the code which type of security in those plugin.

So, please suggest me how to develop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Backup-buddy and gravity forms are used "filemtime" function for security purpose,because there are no any way to prevent user to modify code. because wordpress plugin are fully under control in user (open source).